# Cannot write to newly created file

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I have an ubuntu server. I created a simple `index.html` file using `touch`. and tried to use `nano` and it turns out the permission is denied. Why is this? If I just made the file on the server why wouldn't I have write access in the first place? My second question is if I wanted to change the permissions to the number format `644` (is that what a html file on the server should be set to?) how do I view what it currently is how do I convert `-rw-rw-r--` to the numeral format? I want to view `-ls -l` with the numeral permissions format rather then `-rw-rw-r--`. The `index.html` file is running on the server alright.

```
thomas@vannevar:~/public/example.org/public$ touch index.html
thomas@vannevar:~/public/example.org/public$ ls
index.html
thomas@vannevar:~/public/example.org/public$ nano index.html

Error reading /home/thomas/.nano_history: Permission denied

Press Enter to continue starting nano.

thomas@vannevar:~/public/example.org/public$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thomas thomas 0 May 17 13:57 index.html
thomas@vannevar:~/public/example.org/public$
```

THIS WORKS

http://pricklytech.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/ubuntu-nano-error-reading-home-nano_history-permission-denied/

Comment: The error pertains to the file `/home/thomas/.nano_history`, not to index.html.  Check the permissions for that file, and the parent directory of that file (i.e., `ls -l /home/thomas/.nano_history` and `ls -ld /home/thomas/`).  Also, for octal permission notation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Octal_notation

Comment: The permission denied is for /home/thomas/.nano_history because its having trouble reading it. What does ls -l /home/thomas/.nano_history say?

Comment: -rw------- 1 root root 111 May 17 14:13 /home/thomas/.nano_history

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is reading nano's history file (.nano_history), as indicated very clearly in this massively whitespaced error line:

```
thomas@vannevar:~/public/example.org/public$ nano index.html

Error reading /home/thomas/.nano_history: Permission denied

Press Enter to continue starting nano.
```

This is opened prior to nano opening your file (which works fine because 644 is okay for this)

Looks like your home folder/.nano_history's permissions might be set too tight.

---

Following your comment:

`-rw------- 1 root root 111 May 17 14:13 /home/thomas/.nano_history`

As you can see only root's user has read and write permissions, no one else.

You want to do `sudo chown thomas:thomas ~/.nano_history` to fix this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Given what you have shown, your problem is almost certainly related to your use of `sudo nano` at some point in the past to edit a file.  Nano created a history file in the home directory, but with root permissions.

Use `sudo rm /home/thomas/.nano_history` or `sudo chown thomas:thomas /home/thomas/.nano_history` to fix the permissions on that file.

Many programs you run with sudo may have a side-effect of creating root-owned files in your home directory if you are not careful.  If you know this is going to happen with a particular program like nano, you may be better off using `sudo -i` to start a new shell with a root environment, and then running your commands.

Answer (score 0):

permissions are fairly simple to understand.  there are 3 places in each 'group' for permissions.  read, write, execute.  so, you can think of it as 3 sets of 3 bits.

as an example, the permission set `-rw-rw-r--` equates to `-110110100`.  you can break those up into groups of 3 bits (so `rw-`, `rw-`, and `r--` => `110`, `110`, `100`).  Convert those groups of 3 bits into octal ( since 2^3 == 8 ) and boom!  you got your number code.

for given example:
`110`= 6
`110`= 6
`100`= 4

shortcut way: the 'execute' bit (x) adds 1 to the octal value, the 'write' bit (w) adds 2, and the 'read' bit (r) adds 4.

(644 would be -rw-r--r--)

Comment: :tips hat:  i'm not sure that the leading dash does (the dash before the first 'rw-' group) so i'm not sure how it factors into the numeric representation.  sorry.

Comment: The leading dash turns into a 'd' for directories.

Comment: ahhh, i see.  d for directory, - for file, p for named pipe...

wikipedia, i love you

Comment: getting octal to show up in ls http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/newbie/21722-command-shows-me-permissions-file-octal.html

Comment: huh.  looks like you found the answer on your own.  the google-fu is somewhat strong (if slow to appear) in this one.  also, i prefer to just calc it in my head.  it's only 3 bits after all.